# Getting error as Cannot find module for Entities

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In have created new Component and new entities, Those Entities imported in new componenet  and old component
while taking `ng build`  getting error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module ../entities/user`  in new Componenet, not showing error old component.

**New Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../entities/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usermanagement-page',
  templateUrl: './usermanagement-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usermanagement-page.component.scss']
})
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {
  user:User

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**`Path :src/app/usermanagement-page`**

**Entity:**

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    role: string;
    status: string;
    lastLoginTime: number;
    accessCount: string;
    region: string
}
```

**`Entity Path :src/app/entities`**

Comment: Can you please share the path in which path your entity file?

Comment: Please check the path of your entity it's proper?

Comment: @ Aman Gojariya  Same path adding in old component and taking build not showing error, it shwoing error only newly created componenet

Comment: your both components are in same directory or folder?

Comment: No it is different folder:
src/app/device-page

Comment: Okay then please replace path of entity ./entities/user in your new component

Comment: working....Thanks a lot

Comment: can you please mark as right my answer? if it's works

Comment: If you are new on angular. I have worked in angular since 3 years. I am working as a freelancer. If you have any project then let me know I will work for you as a freelancer

Comment: My skype id is in my profile. You can contact me directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below import statement in your new component

```
import {User} from './entities/user';
```